# Python & PyInstaller : Py to Exe ImportError Problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-storage, exe, pyinstaller

I'm using Python 3.6.5 and I've built my application in py file -it works fine-, and I can run it on cmd perfectly. So I want to built its exe file.

I tried with cx_freeze, py2exe but they didn't work for me.

Lastly I tried with PyInstaller, it looks successfully completed; but when I'm running my exe file, I have this error and I tried many ways to solve this but I didn't. The error is in this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIDlH.jpg)

`ImportError: Failed to import the Cloud Storage library for Python. Make sure to install the "google-cloud-storage" module.`

I'm so sure that I've installed `google-cloud-storage` and `requests` packages (I checked many times with `pip install google-cloud-storage` and `pip install google-resumable-media[requests]` and it says `Requirements already installed`

What I've tried are;

-adding google folders from `site-packages` folder to `dist` folder
-installing grpio (already installed)
-changing google hooks files' inside

But I didn't find any solution.

What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Pictures aren't any good around here - please include the relevant parts of the error in the actual question

Comment: @Shadow I added the last sentence of error to question, what should I add more? you can see whole error in link